# How should I enable cl_khr_fp64 in OpenCL?

Tags: double, opencl, gpu, gpgpu

I'm trying to get `double` precision to work in my OpenCL kernel but I'm having problems enabling `cl_khr_fp64`.  If I put `#pragma OPENCL EXTENSION cl_khr_fp64 : enable` at the top of my kernel file and define a variable `double u = 5.0;` then it defines it and allows me to `+-*/` on `u`.  But if I try to do any math functions, for example `double u = exp(5.0);` it throws an error that it can't find the overloaded `exp` function for type `double`.  Something weird I found is that if I check if `cl_khr_fp64` is defined via

```
#ifdef cl_khr_fp64
#pragma OPENCL EXTENSION cl_khr_fp64 : enable
#elif defined(cl_amd_fp64)
#pragma OPENCL EXTENSION cl_amd_fp64 : enable
#else
#error "Double precision floating point not supported by OpenCL implementation."
#endif
```

Then it throws the error that double precision isn't supported.  If I just say to enable it then it gets enabled, but if I check to see if it *is able to be enabled*, then it says it can't.

I've checked the extensions on my card and `cl_khr_fp64` is listed and I also checked the `CL_DEVICE_DOUBLE_FP_CONFIG` using `clGetDeviceInfo` and it returns 63.  I'm using a MacPro on Yosemite with the AMD FirePro D700.  I'm wondering if I enabled `cl_khr_fp64` in the wrong place or something.  The contents of my `mykernel.cl` file are below.  It's just a modification of the Apple 'hello_world' OpenCL Xcode project.  The code, as written works just fine, but if I change the line from `double u = (5.0);` to `double u = exp(5.0);` it doesn't work.  Ultimately I want to use math functions on `double` variables.  Any help would be greatly appreciated!

```
#pragma OPENCL EXTENSION cl_khr_fp64 : enable

__kernel void square5(global double* input, global double* output, double mul,int nv)
{
    size_t i = get_global_id(0);
    double u = (5.0);
    float left = u/1.2;
    if(i==0) {
        output[i] = mul*pow((float)u,left)*input[i]*input[i];
    } else if (i==nv-1) {
        output[i] = mul*u*input[i]*input[i];
    } else {
        output[i] = 0.25*mul*u*(input[i-1] + input[i+1])*(input[i-1] + input[i+1]);
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm experiencing exactly the same problem... On Sierra and Yosemite. Did you manage to solve it?

Answer (score 4):

Double precision was made a core-optional feature in OpenCL 1.2 (which should be the version that your device supports under OS X). This means that you shouldn't need to enable the extension in order to use it, if it is supported by the device. Enabling the extension shouldn't have any negative effect however.

You are not doing anything wrong, so this is likely a bug in Apple's OpenCL implementation. The same code (with the `exp()` function) compiles fine on my Macbook for the devices that support double precision. So, if your device definitely reports that it supports double precision, then you should file a bug in [Apple's Bug Reporting System](https://developer.apple.com/bug-reporting/).

Comment: :Thank you, this has been bugging me for 6 months.  I do indeed have to include the `#pragma ...` to even define `double u = 5.0;`. If I don't include that line it throws the error "error: use of type 'double' requires cl_khr_fp64 extension to be enabled".  I get the same problem when I try to run this on my CPU also.

Comment: Would you mind sharing the main file that you used to call this kernel?  I've tried it on my mid2012 Macbook Pro using the CPU and it has the same error.  I've linked the `OpenCL.framework` and the `Accelerate.framework` and included `<math.h>` but it still won't run.

Comment: Sure, it's just this trivial command-line program to compile an OpenCL source file: https://gist.github.com/jrprice/abf644ef6032538655bf#file-oclc-c (I compile with `gcc oclc.c -o oclc -framework OpenCL`).